# Eric Andre had a dream

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, letters

> Eric Andre had a dream.

**What did he dream?**

*Hint* $\downarrow$ (the answer does require knowledge, though I'd assume it's pretty common to know about it)

> "I am Eric Andre!"

---

#### Not part of the puzzle. TL;DR

This is my 100th post and you know what, I prepared a huge meta puzzle for my 100th post.

And then life got in the way. In fact, my computer screen broke and I can't even access it. I'm on my school laptop now... and it is likely all my data on my PC is all gone.

But you know what, who cares. What makes 100 a special number anyway? 101, for example, is just as special as 100. 100 is a squared number, but 101? That's the sum of *two* squared numbers. Oh, and it's prime. Same stuff for their binary representations, coincidentally.

So yah. Anyways, I ain't gonna forfeit my time on PSE because my egotistic ways want me to make a "golden" post as my 100th. Pfft. That's just gonna cause me to procrastinate anyways, and I've got other things going on in life. So, here is another one-sentenced puzzle (a "one-line wonder"), since you guys liked that.

---

Enjoy :)

<sub>P.S. I might give a 100rep bounty award to celebrate :P</sub>

Comment: Oh yeah, and I changed my name from *Mr Pie* to... Feeds. Yeah, didn't know that I have to wait 30 days before I could change my name back... eh well, as they say, trial and error goes a long way ;) (oh, and thanks to the first upvoter - that was quick :P)

Comment: I haven't watched the show but I'm assuming it has something to do with rot13(Qernzynaq snyyf, gur ynfg rcvfbqr bs gur fubj).

Comment: @Abbas no, sorry, not that. I don't actually know what show you are referring to. If there is a famous celebrity called Eric Andre or something, that is unrelated. Nice try, though :)

Comment: Hate to tell you bud, but 100 is also the sum of two squares... ;-)

Comment: @Feeds I'm missing **Mr. Pie** :(

Comment: @Ak19 I know :_(

Comment: @Stiv 64+36... dammit! Or even the trial 0+100 haha

Comment: To be fair I also hate to tell you exactly how long it took me to work out which two squares summed to 101. Proper facepalm moment when it dawned on me...

Comment: @Stiv - 100 and 1 :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

He dreamed

> The **American Dream**
>  Which cannot be spelled without Eric Andre - Am[Eric][an Dre]am

Comment: Good job, and welcome to Puzzling! :)

Comment: Thank you! I love Eric Andre, but I have to admit, I started watching after the "Let me in!" memes.

Comment: Also, congrats on your 100th post!

Comment: Hah, thanks! Any association with celebrities by the name of Eric Andre is completely coincidental - but lucky him! He has a great name! :D

Comment: Thank you for a great riddle @Feeds, short and sweet!

Comment: This fellow seems very insistent. "*Am* Eric Andre! Am!"

Answer (score 6):

Long shot. His dream was...

> to make 100 posts.

Because...

> The hint clearly states "I am Eric Andre" which makes me think YOU, the OP, are someone named Eric Andre.

Therefore...

> Your dream was to make 100 posts, as you said in your TL;DR

Comment: Good try, but here was what the hint was really trying to say: (ROT13) V nz Revp Naqer --> V nzRevpNa qer :)

Comment: > "Not part of the puzzle."